# Display Google Typeface at Random on Click

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I'm trying to get the text on my page to display color and font at random on click. Color is working but I can't get the font to change. The console is telling me that the code is working but it isn't displaying.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.header').click(function() { 
    $(".header").toggleClass("headerChange");
    var color = randmColor();
    $(".header").css("color", color);

    var fontType = [ "Lily Script One", "Monoton"];
    $(".header").css("fontfamily", fontType[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)]);
  });
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lily+Script+One');
```

I'm thinking it's the way it's calling the CSS but I'm new to coding and stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a hypen in `"font-family"`. Just change your penultimate line:

```
$(".header").css("font-family", fontType[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)]);
```

Problem of changing `"font-family"` property was already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654708/jquery-changing-font-family-and-font-size?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Of course you should also be sure that your CSS file is linked in your HTML via `<link>` tag.

Comment: Hi Karol, I changed the line to read with the text that you provided but it doesn't seem to be working. Any other ideas? I do have the link to the google font in a separate css file that is linked in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

In your html you will need to make sure to have:

```
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lily+Script+One'); 
    </style>
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab');
    </style>
```

And your CSS you won't set a font and it'll just start off as whatever default font you have and then get changed with your javascript to the random font.

Comment: Firstly, you can do this in just one `<style>` tag scope. Secondly, the same can be reached just by linking external CSS file via `<link>` tag (and that's cleaner approach).