# jQuery and select tag HTML not changing page

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

currently, I'm trying to have the user select a font from the drop-down box and when the pick lets say Times New Roman, all the text on the page changes to that font. I have the basics down but I can't figure out the order of the placement.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  //text
   $("#font option:selected").val();

  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="about_turtles">
  <center><p>This is a test</p></center>
</div>

<div id="font_buttons">
  <select id="font">
  <option value="helvetica">Helvetica</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this simple code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('#font').change(function(){
var font = $(this).val();

$('*').css("font-family", font);
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like your only getting the value of what is selected.

However I think what you are after is an event listener. 
Something like this:

```
$("#font").change(function () {
    var family= this.value;
    $("#about_turtles").css("font-family",family);
  });
```

I would also store the font family names within the value of each option element in  your select list.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjc72o8p/)

Have a look at this for more help: [jQuery changing font family and font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654708/jquery-changing-font-family-and-font-size)